# What is "git pack-redundant -all" actually doing?

Tags: git

The documentation of `pack-redundant` has no information which pack is actually meant as redundant. And also it recommended to delete only packs containing unreachable objects.

Can I remove all redundant packs from repository, is it safe? Where is no any information actually. Our repositories are about 300GB on disk, and redundant packs are about 150GB. So, that's why I ask this question. If I  remove some required packs, it will be not very good.

Answer (score 1):

Since Oct. 2016, that operation has evolved somewhat in its implementation.
Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) will bring performance improvement.
Update Jan. 2021: this command is now obsolete. See second part of this answer.
Update Q2 2023: `git pack-redundant` is deprecated. See at the end oof this answer.

That patch, in turn, helps to illustrate what `git pack-redundant --all` is actually doing.

See [commit 0e37abd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e37abd2e89d475500e93a6368f1f054ca2fec55), [commit 4bc0cc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bc0cc12c19f00380052d0cfaf4e71e0a4630f41), [commit 3011177](https://github.com/git/git/commit/301117764041101ae228e8e33c12c0b232b06408), [commit 3173a94](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3173a94d577e14501039e85f333e9c98cbd92667) (02 Feb 2019) by [Jiang Xin (`jiangxin`)](https://github.com/jiangxin).
See [commit 3084a01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3084a01e5efefc57d8f52562c82fd41799379697), [commit 8822859](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8822859363a86ade287c7deb07224af345a699f4) (02 Feb 2019) by [Sun Chao (`sunchao`)](https://github.com/sunchao).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cf0879f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf0879f7e98d2213503622f780d2ab0dd3f93477), 07 Mar 2019)</sup>

> ### `pack-redundant`: new algorithm to find min packs

> When calling `git pack-redundant --all`, if there are too many local packs and too many redundant objects within them, the too deep iteration of `get_permutations` will exhaust all the resources, and the process of `git pack-redundant` will be killed.
>
> The following script could create a repository with too many redundant
> packs, and running `git pack-redundant --all` in the `test.git` repo
> will die soon.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> repo="$(pwd)/test.git"
> work="$(pwd)/test"
> i=1
> max=199
>
> if test -d "$repo" || test -d "$work"; then
>   echo >&2 "ERROR: '$repo' or '$work' already exist"
>   exit 1
> fi
>
> git init -q --bare "$repo"
> git --git-dir="$repo" config gc.auto 0
> git --git-dir="$repo" config transfer.unpackLimit 0
> git clone -q "$repo" "$work" 2>/dev/null
>
> while :; do
>    cd "$work"
>    echo "loop $i: $(date +%s)" >$i
>    git add $i
>    git commit -q -sm "loop $i"
>    git push -q origin HEAD:master
>    printf "\rCreate pack %4d/%d\t" $i $max
>    if test $i -ge $max; then break; fi
>
>    cd "$repo"
>    git repack -q
>    if test $(($i % 2)) -eq 0; then
>        git repack -aq
>        pack=$(ls -t $repo/objects/pack/*.pack | head -1)
>        touch "${pack%.pack}.keep"
>    fi
>    i=$((i+1))
> done
> printf "\ndone\n"
> ```
>
> To get the `min` unique pack list, we can replace the iteration in
> `minimize` function with a new algorithm, and this could solve this
> issue:
>
> 1. Get the unique and non_unique packs, add the unique packs to the
>    `min` list.
> 2. Remove the objects of unique packs from non_unique packs, then each
>    object left in the non_unique packs will have at least two copies.
> 3. Sort the non_unique packs by the objects' size, more objects first,
>    and add the first non_unique pack to `min` list.
> 4. Drop the duplicated objects from other packs in the ordered non_unique pack list, and repeat step 3.

You can see it in action in [`t/t5323-pack-redundant.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3173a94d577e14501039e85f333e9c98cbd92667/t/t5323-pack-redundant.sh)

> In order to test `git-pack-redundant`, we will create a number of objects and
> packs in the repository `master.git`.
> The relationship between packs (P1-P8) and objects (T, A-R) is showed in the following chart.
>
> - Objects of a pack will be marked with letter `x`, while
> - objects of redundant packs will be marked with exclamation point `!`, and
> - redundant pack itself will be marked with asterisk `*`.

```
    | T A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R
----+--------------------------------------
P1  | x x x x x x x                       x
P2* |     ! ! ! !   ! ! !
P3  |             x     x x x x x
P4* |                     ! ! ! !     !
P5  |               x x           x x
P6* |                             ! !   !
P7  |                                 x x
P8* |   !
----+--------------------------------------
ALL | x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

> Another repository `shared.git` has unique objects (X-Z), while other objects
> (marked with letter s) are shared through alt-odb (of `master.git`). The
> relationship between packs and objects is as follows:

> ```
>     | T A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R   X Y Z
> ```

```
----+----------------------------------------------
Px1 |   s s s                                 x x x
Px2 |         s s s                           x x x
```

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), warn loudly when the "`pack-redundant`" command, which has been left stale with almost unusable performance issues, gets used, as we no longer want to recommend its use (instead just "`repack -d`" instead).

See [commit c3b5847](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3b58472be2c647cd0c5af328980b15bd3f43b69) (25 Aug 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dfcd905](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfcd90506998c1de8d8ef86431c86ef9ed626c30), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pack-redundant`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3b58472be2c647cd0c5af328980b15bd3f43b69): gauge the usage before proposing its removal
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> The subcommand is unusably slow and the reason why nobody reports it as a performance bug is suspected to be the absense of users.
> Let's show a big message that asks the user to tell us that they still care about the command when an attempt is made to run the command, with an escape hatch to override it with a command line option.
>
> In a few releases, we may turn it into an error and keep it for a few more releases before finally removing it (during the whole time, the plan to remove it would be interrupted by end user raising hand).

So if you are using this command, you will see:

```
'git pack-redundant' is nominated for removal.
If you still use this command, please add an extra
option, '--i-still-use-this', on the command line
and let us know you still use it by sending an e-mail
to <git@vger.kernel.org>.  Thanks.
```

---

Before Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git pack-redundant`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5e4070e12808441cd0a21e45e1af52a7f28ddd2e/Documentation/git-pack-redundant.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-redundant))</sup> gave a warning when run, as the command has outlived its usefulness long ago and is nominated for future removal.
Now we escalate to give an error.

See [commit 4406522](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4406522b76138c2bd3d110ac9de0d860ba2be5ed) (23 Mar 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5e4070e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e4070e12808441cd0a21e45e1af52a7f28ddd2e), 04 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`pack-redundant`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4406522b76138c2bd3d110ac9de0d860ba2be5ed): escalate deprecation warning to an error
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> In [c3b5847](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3b58472be2c647cd0c5af328980b15bd3f43b69) ("`pack-redundant`: gauge the usage before proposing its removal", 2020-08-25, Git v2.31.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dfcd90506998c1de8d8ef86431c86ef9ed626c30) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6362826a0409539642a5738db61827e5978e2e4)), we added a big, ugly warning when pack-redundant is run.
> The plan there indicated that we would ratchet that up to an error before finally removing it.
> Since it has been 2.5 years (and 9 releases) since then, let's continue with the plan.
>
> Note that we did get one bite on the warning, which was somebody asking about alternatives:
>
> See [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAKvOHKAFXQwt4D8yUCCkf_TQL79mYaJ=KAKhtpDNTvHJFuX1NA@mail.gmail.com/)
>
> but we didn't undo the ugly warning (and the advice continues to be "`use repack -d`" instead).
>
> There was also some discussion around the time of the deprecation that pack-redundant was invoked by the bitbake tool, and it still seems to do [so now](https://git.openembedded.org/bitbake):
>
> That use should probably just go away in favor of an occasional repack (which probably even happens via auto-gc after fetch these days).
>
> But since neither of those data points caused us to cancel the deprecation plan by dropping the warning, it seems like we should proceed with the next step.

---

Git 2.41 (Q2 2023) confirms and documents that "pack-redundant" is marked as deprecated.

See [commit fcf31da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcf31daae4cdb71ec367aac0d2cbeef779e97451) (28 Mar 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ae61aec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae61aecb9e338ab02a7d3cced40135ab43880093), 06 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`pack-redundant`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcf31daae4cdb71ec367aac0d2cbeef779e97451): document deprecation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Running the command itself has generated a warning for several versions, which has recently been upgraded to an error.
> Let's also make sure the documentation mentions what is going on.
> This also gives us a good spot to explain the reasoning and recommend alternatives.

`git pack-redundant` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fcf31daae4cdb71ec367aac0d2cbeef779e97451/Documentation/git-pack-redundant.txt#L14-L27):

> ### WARNING
>
> `git pack-redundant` has been deprecated and is scheduled for removal in
> a future version of Git. Because it can only remove entire duplicate
> packs and not individual duplicate objects, it is generally not a useful
> tool for reducing repository size. You are better off using `git gc` to
> do so, which will put objects into a new pack, removing duplicates.
>
> Running `pack-redundant` without the `--i-still-use-this` flag will fail
> in this release. If you believe you have a use case for which
> `pack-redundant` is better suited and oppose this removal, please
> contact the Git mailing list at git@vger.kernel.org. More information
> about the list is available at https://git-scm.com/community.

Answer (score 0):

The man page of `git pack-redundant` says

> The output is suitable for piping to `xargs rm` if you are in the root of the repository.

which really suggest the output list files that are **not** necessary. I have just run

```
~ git pack-redundant --all | xargs rm
```

on a repository I have (size similar to yours), and `git fsck` seems to be happy after that.

I think you could just clone on the same machine, keep the new repository and test the above command on the old one. I think `git clone` does hard links when cloning local repositories (i.e. using a file path, specifying `localhost:stuff` doesn't work), so the clone shouldn't take much more space.